# PyTorch to CoreMl converted model spikes RAM usage

Tags: swift, xcode, pytorch, coreml, coremltools

```
from numpy.core.numeric import indices
import torch
import numpy as np
from transformers import GPTNeoForCausalLM
import coremltools as ct
with torch.no_grad():

    class ModelClass(torch.nn.Module):
        def __init__(self, model=None):
            super(ModelClass, self).__init__()
            self.next_token_predictor = model

        def forward(self, x):
            sentence = x
            predictions, _ = self.next_token_predictor(sentence)
            topKProbs, topKIndexes = torch.topk(predictions[-1, :], 100, dim=0, sorted=True)
            return sentence, topKProbs, topKIndexes

    token_predictor = GPTNeoForCausalLM.from_pretrained("EleutherAI/gpt-neo-125M", torchscript=True).eval()
    
    random_tokens = torch.randint(1, (1,))
    traced_token_predictor = torch.jit.trace(token_predictor, random_tokens)

    model = ModelClass(model=traced_token_predictor)
    scripted_model = torch.jit.script(model)

    mlmodel = ct.convert(
        scripted_model,
        # Range for the sequence dimension to be between [1, 64]
        inputs=[ct.TensorType(name="sentence", shape=(ct.RangeDim(1, 64),), dtype=np.int32)]
    )
    spec = mlmodel.get_spec()
    ct.utils.rename_feature(spec, 'topKProbs_1_0', 'topKProbs')
    ct.utils.rename_feature(spec, 'topKProbs_1_1', 'topKIndexes')
    mlmodel = ct.models.MLModel(spec)
    mlmodel.save("gptNeo125MtopK.mlmodel")
```

PyTorch model size 500mb
CoreModel size: 800mb

Taken this repo

https://github.com/huggingface/swift-coreml-transformers

run custom code

```
//
//  GPT2.swift
//  CoreMLGPT2
//
//  Created by Julien Chaumond on 19/07/2019.
//  Copyright © 2019 Hugging Face. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import CoreML


class NEO {
    
    private let model = try! gptNeo125MtopK()
    public let tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer()
    public let seqLen = 64
    private let strategy: DecodingStrategy
    
    init(strategy: DecodingStrategy = .topK(8)) {
        self.strategy = strategy
    }
    
    /// Main prediction loop:
    /// Predict next token from array of previous tokens.
    /// - featurization
    /// - model inference
    /// - Decoding according to the model's `strategy`
    func predict(tokens: [Int]) -> Int {
        let maxTokens = (tokens.count > seqLen)
            ? Array(tokens[..<seqLen])
            : tokens
        /// Pad input_ids on the right, up to `seqLen`:
        let input_ids = MLMultiArray.from(
            maxTokens + Array(repeating: 0, count: seqLen - maxTokens.count)
        )
        let input = gptNeo125MtopKInput(sentence: input_ids)
        let output = try! model.prediction(input: input)
        
        let sampleIndex = Math.sample(
            indexes: MLMultiArray.toIntArray(output.topKIndexes),
            probs: MLMultiArray.toFloatArray(output.topKProbs)
        )
        return sampleIndex
    }
    
    
    /// Main generation loop.
    ///
    /// Will generate next `nTokens` (defaults to 10).
    /// Calls an incremental `callback` for each new token, then returns the generated string at the end.
    ///
    func generate(text: String, nTokens: Int = 5) -> Void {
        var tokens = tokenizer.encode(text: text)
        var newTokens: [Int] = []
        for i in 0..<nTokens {
            let nextToken = predict(tokens: tokens)
            tokens.append(nextToken)
            print(tokenizer.decode(tokens: tokens))
        }
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
    init() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let neo = NEO()
            neo.generate(text: "The Manhattan bridge is")
        }
    }
}
```

On the first run I got over 19GB RAM usage on a first iteration, on second ... N iterations RAM usage fall less than 500MB

[image]

Please, help to convert this model to run it on <1GB RAM usage, thanks!

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: No, I use GPT2 model atm  from https://github.com/huggingface/swift-coreml-transformers, but i wish to solve it somehow.

Comment: Having the same issue. Memory usage with a fixed shape using torchscript is much smaller for a GPT2 like model, similar to the one manually created by huggingface coreml transformers.